# Confusion about "too...to"

Tags: descriptive-grammar

I thought the combination of **too...to** always resulted in a negative meaning, as in this sentence:

> He is **too** smart **to** fall for your tricks.

(which, of course, means *he is so smart that he cannot fall for your tricks*)

Then, I came across this:

> He is **too** ready **to** believe anything you tell him.

And that does not negate anything at all. Sources [like this](https://www.englishgrammar.org/tooto/), however, state that **too...to** is always a negative construction, and yet, as I can see, it is not always a negative construction. So, other than the context itself, is there a rule to determine what **too...to** implies?

Comment: depending on the intonation, the second one can also mean 
"he is ready **too** to believe...", as a positive sentence

Comment: You second example implicitly negates ***what one might expect/desire*** (or ***what it would be in his best interests to do***). But please don't say I'm too keen on migrating question like this to ELL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grammatical construction **too + adjective/adverb + to infinitive** has a negative meaning. But in order to get the negative meaning, there should have a contrasting connotation in the total sense denoted by the *adj/adv* and the *to infinitive.* The OP's second sentence does not have this contrasting effect to create a negative sense by the *too...to infinitive* construction.

Compare: 1.He is too smart to fall for your tricks - negative sense- (smart but to fall for tricks - a contrast )

2.He is too ready to believe anything you tell him  - No negative sense - (ready to believe - no contrast)

More example sentences from the same [site](https://www.englishgrammar.org/tooto/) linked by the OP can show this:

> *He was too nervous to perform well on the stage.* (Nervous but to perform well - contrast)
>
> *I was too busy to talk to her.* ( Busy but to find time to talk - contrast)
>
> *The task was too difficult to do without help.* ( Difficult but to do without help.)

Comment: So, the "always negative" summary is wrong?  Is that what you're saying?

Comment: @Xanne, No, *too...to infinitive* construction is always with a negative meaning. Others (the ones like OP's 2nd sentence ) have nothing to do with this construction. They are ordinary statements meaning *He is always ready to believe anything...* Moreover, *ready* is a non-gradable adjective, and cannot be modified by adverbs like *very*, *too* etc.

Comment: Yes and sideways, isn’t *too* always negative anyway?

What would be a positive equivalent to *He is too smart to fall for your tricks*, please? What positive phrase using *too* could answer *does that fit?* as *It’s too big* does? 

Isn’t even *too good to pass up* a negative by comparison? How could a positive opposite for *too tight* or *too flimsy* use the same construction? *Not too good to pass up* works purely because it's logically a double negative…

Comment: *He is too smart to fall for your tricks* means *He is so smart that he can't/won't fall for your tricks; not like, *He is very smart but he can/will fall for your tricks. That's why it is called the *too...to infinitive* construction has a negative meaning. All sentences/clauses/phrases containing *too + adjective/adverbs* are not negative.